# Honeycomb grid with 9 combs CSS HTML JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Could you please assist me in setting up a honeycomb grid like the one below ?

[image: honeycomb]

Ive tried using https://github.com/nasirkhan/honeycombs
But once the viewport changes it changes the layout.

I would only need this to be bout 450-580 px wide and not necessarily responsive or just collapsing in to 3/3/3

Comment: @DavidThomas I've provided the library where the Demo is, i've achieved my result but explained that due to libraries responsivness it messes up the grid.

Comment: In what way does that constitute the minimum reproducible example code? Your relevant code must be in your question, otherwise we don't have any insight into what you're doing or what might be going wrong. Nor should those people trying to help you with your specific problem be expected to visit external sites in order to do so. As it happens your question appears to be a duplicate anyway, so hopefully you'll find a useful answer to the other question.

Comment: @dExIT I have a flexible solution for you: https://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/pozwLwJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to try and make your own, try `clip-path`. It's an easy way to get shapes like hexagons. To see what you can do with clip-paths I find this link very usefull: https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/.

Some more info about clip paths: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/clip-path/

And an example:

```css
img{
clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
```

---

U can put multiple next to eachother and play with positioning:

```css
.canvas{
  width: 500px;
}

img{
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
}

.comb{
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 165px;
}

.comb:nth-of-type(2n){
  top: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="canvas">
<div class="comb"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></div>
<div class="comb"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></div>
<div class="comb"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></div>
<div class="comb"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></div>
<div class="comb"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></div>
<div class="comb"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></div>
<div class="comb"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></div>
<div class="comb"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></div>
<div class="comb"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></div>
<div class="comb"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></div>
<div class="comb"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></div>
<div class="comb"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></div>
```

Comment: Amazing, i will see what i can try out

Comment: @dExIT see updated answer, this way it is easier to add more elements to it.

Comment: Im trying to rotate it but your solution is 90% and i've learned something new today cheers :)